# How to create auto increment values of a column with character combination?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table which contains a column **ID**. I want to store values as 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', ...
But here I will not insert the values manually. I want it to work it like **auto_increment** where the numbers will auto increase with P as concatenated.

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID       | varchar(10)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| NAME     | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CATEGORY | varchar(15)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| EMAIL    | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PASSWORD | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This is my table structure

Comment: You could do it with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.